# Why is it called numerical integration when we numerically solve differential equations?

Tags: numerical-methods, terminology

This has been bugging me literally for years.

When numerically simulating a system of differential equations (e.g., with Runge-Kutta or Euler methods), we are using the derivative to estimate the value of the function at the next time step. Why is this called *numerical integration* or *integration* rather than simply numerical simulation or *function estimation* or something?

I have not found this nomenclature discussed, and would love to see the origins. I am probably Googling wrong and missing something obvious. My *guess* is that from the fundamental theorem, an operation that brings you from $\dot{x}$ to x is by definition integration, so we are technically doing numerical integration?

I suppose it could be that all of the same terms are involved as when you calculate the integral using a Riemann sum (or related techniques). But for the differential equation we are not calculating the area but the value of the function at the next time step, so it doesn't seem like an integral in that sense.

Comment: Solving a differential equation is also called "integrating" it, because finding a primitive of a function (integrating it) is solving the simplest kind of ordinary differential equation.

Comment: Something I had forgotten is that individual trajectories are also called 'integral curves' in many math texts -- I always call them trajectories or individual solutions in my scientific contexts.

Comment: “[One of the miseries of life is that everybody names things a little bit wrong, and so it makes everything a little harder to understand.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKWGGDXe5MA&feature=youtu.be&t=296) — Richard Feynman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Integration* is the general term for the resolution of a differential equation.

You probably know the simple case of antiderivatives,

$$\int f(x)\,dx$$ which in fact solve the ODE $$y'(x)=f(x)$$ via an *integral*.

The same term is used when you solve, say

$$y'(x)=y(x)+5,$$

giving

$$y(x)=ce^x+5.$$

You *integrate* the equation. Sometimes, the solution itself is called an integral.

You can integrate by *analytical* methods, and also by *numerical* methods.

Comment: So is it basically this: "an operation that brings you from $\dot{x}$ to x is by definition integration"?

Comment: @neuronet: can be more general, any kind of differential equation.

Comment: Ok thanks, so basically just what you said in your answer: if you have an equation involving $\dot{x}$ (or higher-order versions),  and solve for x, that is 'integration'. I had forgotten that plots of specific solutions are sometimes called integral curves.

Answer (score -1):

A solver which solves differential equations by integrating variables step by step is called differential equation solver or integrator.

Suppose that it is a forced mass damper spring equation:
Fx=m* d2x+b* dx+k* x , where x is a function of t => x(t), d2x is second derivative of x, dx is first derivative of x with respect to t. k is stiffness coefficient , b is damping coeff. , m is the mass.

We suppose time interval between t[n] and t[n+1] is fixed and it is dt.

create initial values for x(0)=0 and dx(0)=0
You find d2x for next point like this:

d2x[i+1]=(Fx-b*dx[i]-k*x[i])/m

**Then you integrate (accumulate values) Hence the name integrator:**

dx[i+1]=dx[i]+d2x[i+1]*dt
x[i+1]=x[i]+dx[i]*dt

then you increase i , i=i+1 and do it all over again ...

This is why it is called integrator...

**Here it will be more clearer directly using integrals :**

See this section ?

```
  Fxb+=Fx[i]*dt # first integral of Fx wrt dt 
  Fxb2+=Fxb*dt # second integral of Fx wrt dt**2
  xb+=x[i]*dt # first integral of x wrt dt 
  xb2+=xb*dt # second integral of Fx wrt dt**2
```

Code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import animation, rc
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import time

m=1
b=0.1
k=100
t=sp.symbols('t')
x=sp.Function('x')
Fx=100*sp.sin(3*t)
expr=m*sp.diff(x(t),t,2)+b*sp.diff(x(t),t)+k*x(t)-Fx
x=sp.dsolve(expr,x(t)).rhs
C2=sp.solve(x.subs(t,0))[0]
x=x.subs('C2',C2)
C1=sp.solve(sp.diff(x,t).subs(t,0))[0]
x=x.subs('C1',C1)
print(x)

f=sp.lambdify(t,x)

T=5
dt=0.01
t_analytic=np.linspace(0,T,int(T/dt))
x_analytic=f(t_analytic)

######################################
T=5
dt=0.01
t=np.linspace(0,T,int(T/dt))
m=1
b=0.1
k=100

Fx=100*np.sin(3*t)

x=np.zeros(len(t))

tdump=time.time()
Fxb,Fxb2,xb,xb2=[0,0,0,0]

for i in range(0,len(t)-1):
  Fxb+=Fx[i]*dt # first integral of Fx wrt dt 
  Fxb2+=Fxb*dt # second integral of Fx wrt dt**2
  xb+=x[i]*dt # first integral of x wrt dt 
  xb2+=xb*dt # second integral of Fx wrt dt**2
  x[i+1]=(Fxb2-b*xb-k*xb2)/m

plt.plot(t[2:],x[2:],'black')

print('Integrating solv. Elapsed:',time.time()-tdump)
#plt.plot(t,np.diff(x)/dt,'g--')

err=np.sum(np.abs(x-f(t)))
total=np.sum(np.abs(x_analytic))
print('Integrating solv. error ratio is:',err/total)

def mydiff(x, t):
  m = 1 # Mass
  b = 0.1 # Damping constant
  k = 100 # Stiffness of the spring
  F = 100*np.sin(3*t)

  dx1dt = x[1]
  dx2dt = (F - b*x[1] - k*x[0])/m
  dxdt = [dx1dt, dx2dt]
  return dxdt

T=5
#dt=0.01
t=np.linspace(0,T,int(T/dt))
x_init = [0,0]
# Solve ODE
tdump=time.time()
x = odeint(mydiff, x_init, t)
x1 = x[:,0]
x2 = x[:,1]
print('odeint Elapsed:',time.time()-tdump)
# Plot the Results
plt.plot(t,x1,'r--')

err=np.sum(np.abs(x1-f(t)))
total=np.sum(np.abs(x_analytic))
print('odeint Error ratio is:',err/total)
```

[image]
There are a lot sophisticated version of this itteration. Runge-Kutta , ADAMS method. There implicit and explicit versions of this.

There is an MIT course notes of R.Sureshkumar:
https://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Course_Notes/Differential_Equations_Notes/lec24.html

Comment: In what way does this answer the question on why the word "integration" is used for a procedure that is not just the evaluation of a (Riemann) integral? (Which is in contrast frequently called "quadrature".)

Comment: I thought, he thinks we use derivatives (x[i]-x[i-1])dt to calculate next value he does not see it as an integration process. So I tried to show him solving differential equations are accumulating some values in buffer, essentially integrating the equation all over in time steps.

Comment: Read carefully he thinks it is a function estimation or numerical simulation. It is not. It is just simply integrating variables having a constraint which we call function. It would be a function estimation or numerical simulation If we had approximate a polynomial or other function for a limited time and vector step, like it is done in finite element analysis ...

Comment: This could be a valid point, but then you need to restructure your answer. The first paragraphs are definitions, they do not answer the question of "why" for the choice of words "integrator", "integrate". In the middle you make the argument "integrate" = "accumulate small contributions", you should move that to the top and strengthen it with some citations.